# Users instead id , Django(wagtail) , Vue

Tags: django, vue.js, wagtail

I want to make a class that returns usename of all users who liked the post. Users will be sent to Vue.
currently the code returns in Vue consol log - 0: {likex: 'ideas.IdeaPage.None'}

models.py

```
class IdeaPage(Page):
    intro = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    body = RichTextField()
    tags = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    likex = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="likex", blank=True)
```

serializer.py

```
class LikeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    likex = serializers.CharField()
    
    class Meta:
        model = IdeaPage
        fields = ["likex"]
```

views.py

```
@authentication_classes([authentication.TokenAuthentication])
@permission_classes([permissions.IsAuthenticated])
class Like(APIView):
    
    def get(self, request, id, format=None):
        ideasl = IdeaPage.objects.get(id=id)
        likepost = IdeaPage.objects.get(id=id)
        likepostZ = likepost.likex.all()
        if request.user in likepost.likex.get_queryset():
            likepost.likex.remove(request.user)
        else:
            likepost.likex.add(request.user)

        serializer = LikeSerializer(likepostZ, many=True)

        return Response(serializer.data)
```

why code return likex: 'ideas.IdeaPage.None'?

Comment: Why is `likex` a `CharField`? It will call `str(..)` and `str(..)` on a `RelatedManager` always returns `app_name.ModelName.None`.

Comment: Furthermore you should *not* implement likes under a GET method: a GET method is supposed to have *no* side-effects: it thus should *not* make modifications to the database. If you want to alter entities, you should use a POST, PUT, PATCH or DELETE method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a `CharField` for the number of likes is "odd". You can simply make use of an `IntegerField`, and annotate the object accordingly, so:

```
class LikeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    likex = serializers.IntegerField(source='num_likes')
    
    class Meta:
        model = IdeaPage
        fields = ['likex']
```

and in the view we annotate the object with the number of likes:

```
from django.db.models import Count
from django.shorcuts import get_object_or_404

@authentication_classes([authentication.TokenAuthentication])
@permission_classes([permissions.IsAuthenticated])
class Like(APIView):
    
    def get(self, request, id, format=None):
        qs = IdeaPage.objects.annotate(
            num_likes=Count('likex')
        )
        like_post = get_object_or_404(qs, pk=id)
        if request.user in like_post.likex.all():
            like_post.likex.remove(request.user)
            like_post.num_likes += 1
        else:
            likepost.likex.add(request.user)
            like_post.num_likes -= 1

        serializer = LikeSerializer(like_post)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

**But**, you should *not* like or dislike an item with a GET request. A GET request ought to be considered safe. Indeed the [section on *safe methods* of the HTTP specifications says](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.1.1):

> In particular, the convention has been established that the **GET and HEAD methods SHOULD NOT have the significance of taking an action other than retrieval. These methods ought to be considered "safe"**. This allows user agents to represent other methods, such as POST, PUT and DELETE, in a special way, so that the user is made aware of the fact that a possibly unsafe action is being requested.

Liking an item thus should be implemented with a POST request. You can implement a GET request to share the number of likes, and thus move the logic to alter the number of likes to the `post(…)` method.

For a list of members you can work with with [**`PrimaryKeyRelatedField`** [DRF-doc]](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield):

```
class LikeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    likex = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True)
    
    class Meta:
        model = IdeaPage
        fields = ['likex']
```

or for usernames with a [**`SlugRelatedField`** [DRF-doc]](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield):

```
class LikeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    likex = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        slug_field='username',
        queryset=User.objects.all(),
        many=True
    )
    
    class Meta:
        model = IdeaPage
        fields = ['likex']
```

then the view is thus defined as:

```
from django.db.models import Count
from django.shorcuts import get_object_or_404

@authentication_classes([authentication.TokenAuthentication])
@permission_classes([permissions.IsAuthenticated])
class Like(APIView):
    
    def get(self, request, id, format=None):
        like_post = get_object_or_404(IdeaPage, pk=id)
        serializer = LikeSerializer(like_post)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    
    def post(self, request, id, format=None):
        like_post = get_object_or_404(IdeaPage, pk=id)
        if request.user in like_post.likex.all():
            like_post.likex.remove(request.user)
        else:
            likepost.likex.add(request.user)
        serializer = LikeSerializer(like_post)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I want to send a list of users to Vue to see if the user has already liked. For example. if reqest.user in likex: dislike else Like. 
I know I should send it via "POST" but this is for learning

Comment: @DrewnyDrzew: then you should work with a `PrimaryKeyRelatedField`, or a `SlugRelatedField`.